# Handling multipart/form-data input

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I just tried using FormDataMultiPart but unfortunately it doesn't seem to
help.
Now I get the following error message:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=----------Ef1gL6cH2ae0gL6Ij5cH2Ef1KM7Ij5 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Is is a server-side or client side problem?

The client side code I have is taken from
[this site](http://tiainen.sertik.net/2009/10/easy-file-upload-in-java-using-jersey.html)

Comment: The exception is complaining that the message is malformed.

Comment: @bmargulies So, the problem is with the upload client?

Comment: You shoudln't be using com.sun.* APIs! Not that this explains your bug, mind, but it is a very bad idea. What if someone tries to run your code on OpenJDK?

Comment: @fge, thanks for the tip. However this code will not run in OpenJDK

Comment: Can't tell for sure without looking at what went on the wire. Use tcpmon or whatever and manually verify. Or if the client is in a browser, Chrome's developer tools will reveal all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A google search for "SEVERE: A message body reader for Java" turns up this nugget at http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/SEVERE-A-message-body-reader-for-Java-class-com-sun-jersey-multipart-FormDataMultiPart-and-Java-typed-td5969276.html

"...Please make sure you have mimepull.jar on the classpath..."

Looks a lot like your stacktrace, no?  I'd have to say something is missing server-side.

Comment: I was wondering how you do file upload in restful clients.  Gotta give this a try.

Comment: I was getting this same error until I added mimepull.jar to the classpath.

Comment: you'll need multipart (get the same version as your jersey server) (mine was http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart/1.14) and notice the dependency section that shows the need for mimepull and provides a link (mimepull-1.6.jar).

Answer (score 4):

resolved:

```
include mimepull-1.6.jar
```